# Capitalize All Titles and Headlines in Chicago Style

Tags: plugins, title, content

I want to capitalize all titles and headlines on my blog according to the Chicago Manual of Style. Since this is a very tedious and time consuming task to do it manually, I thought there must be another way, like a plugin or a piece of code, that goes through all the content and fixes it.

I found this plugin, that is meant to do exactly this: https://github.com/tommcfarlin/title-capitalization-for-wordpress

But it seems to be abandoned and doesn't work on my site. I assume it doesn't work with Gutenberg.

Does anyone know a way to capitalize all titles and headlines, without going through it manually?

Comment: Well, you could use CSS  - text-transform: capitalize; - but that will capitalize the first letter of every word, ie Chicago Manual Of Style vs Chicago Manual of Style. Alternatively, you could export your post and pages into a CSV, run a script there of some sort, and reimport?

Comment: If only there was a script to do this. I searched the web and to my surprise I didn't find anything. If I had a simple PHP script or something, I would know how to implement this in WordPress to run it through my posts. But I didn't find anything that does this.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look a Tom's plugin that you referenced and made a stripped down version that simply runs post titles through the `Title_case` class on-the-fly.

I tested it out, and it works. Unlike the original plugin, the code below just changes titles before they are displayed and not when saving posts.

**Plugin structure:**

```
/wpse-title-case/
    wpse-title-case.php
    /includes/
        class-title-case.php
        locales.json
```

**`wpse-title-case.php`:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE Title Case
Plugin URI:
Description: Apply title case to post titles.
Version: 1.0.0
Author:
Author URI:
License: GPL2/Creative Commons
*/

require trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/class-title-case.php';

function wpse_title_case( $post_title ) {
    $title_case = new Title_Case();
    return $title_case->to_title_case( $post_title );
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_title_case' );
```

**`class-title-case.php`:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Title_Case
 *
 * original Title Case script © John Gruber <daringfireball.net>
 * javascript port © David Gouch <individed.com>
 * PHP port of the above by Kroc Camen <camendesign.com>
 * refactor and mods for contractions and markdown headers by Andy Fragen <andy@thefragens.com>
 */
class Title_Case {

    /**
     * Convert string to title case.
     *
     * @param $title
     *
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function to_title_case( $title ) {
        //remove HTML, storing it for later
        //       HTML elements to ignore    | tags  | entities
        $regx = '/<(code|var)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>|<[^>]+>|&\S+;|#+|\$([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/';
        preg_match_all( $regx, $title, $html, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
        $title = preg_replace( $regx, '', $title );

        //find each word (including punctuation attached)
        preg_match_all( '/[\w\p{L}&`\'‘’"“\.@:\/\{\(\[<>_]+-? */u', $title, $m1, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

        foreach ( $m1[0] as &$m2 ) {

            //shorthand these- "match" and "index"
            list ( $m, $i ) = $m2;

            //correct offsets for multi-byte characters (`PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` returns *byte*-offset)
            //we fix this by recounting the text before the offset using multi-byte aware `strlen`
            $i = mb_strlen( substr( $title, 0, $i ), 'UTF-8' );

            //try to internationalize a bit.
            $locale       = get_locale(); //this makes the lib WordPress specific. :(
            $short_locale = preg_replace( '/_.*$/', '', $locale );

            /**
             * don't know if this is useful -- yet
             *
             * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191664/list-of-all-locales-and-their-short-codes
             */
            $locales = json_decode( file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/locales.json' ) );

            /**
             * Send string to locale-based rules for capitalization.
             */
            switch ( $short_locale ) {
                case 'en': // English
                    $m = $this->english( $m, $i, $title );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //re-splice the title with the change (`substr_replace` is not multi-byte aware)
            $title = mb_substr( $title, 0, $i, 'UTF-8' ) . $m .
                     mb_substr( $title, $i + mb_strlen( $m, 'UTF-8' ), mb_strlen( $title, 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8' );
        }

        //restore the HTML
        foreach ( $html[0] as &$tag ) {
            $title = substr_replace( $title, $tag[0], $tag[1], 0 );
        }

        return $title;
    }

    /**
     * Capitalize based upon English rules.
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param $m string
     * @param $i
     * @param $title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function english( $m, $i, $title ) {
        //find words that should always be lowercase…
        //(never on the first word, and never if preceded by a colon)
        if (
            $i > 0 && mb_substr( $title, max( 0, $i - 2 ), 1, 'UTF-8' ) !== ':' &&
            ! preg_match( '/[\x{2014}\x{2013}] ?/u', mb_substr( $title, max( 0, $i - 2 ), 2, 'UTF-8' ) ) &&
            preg_match( '/^(a(nd?|s|t)?|b(ut|y)|en|for|i[fn]|o[fnr]|t(he|o)|vs?\.?|via)[ \-]/i', $m ) ||

            // Don't capitalize contractions
            preg_match( '/\'(s|t|ll|re|ve|d|m|em)/i', $m )
        ) {
            //…and convert them to lowercase
            $m = mb_strtolower( $m, 'UTF-8' );

        } elseif (
            //else: brackets and other wrappers
        preg_match( '/[\'"_{(\[‘“]/u', mb_substr( $title, max( 0, $i - 1 ), 3, 'UTF-8' ) )
        ) {
            //convert first letter within wrapper to uppercase
            $m = mb_substr( $m, 0, 1, 'UTF-8' );

            //if single letter word, capitalize it
            if ( 1 === mb_strlen( $m, 'UTF-8' ) ) {
                $m = mb_strtoupper( $m, 'UTF-8' );
            } else {
                $m .= mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $m, 1, 1, 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8' ) .
                      mb_substr( $m, 2, mb_strlen( $m, 'UTF-8' ) - 2, 'UTF-8' );
            }
        } elseif (
            //else: do not uppercase these cases
            preg_match( '/[\])}]/', mb_substr( $title, max( 0, $i - 1 ), 3, 'UTF-8' ) ) ||
            preg_match( '/[A-Z]+|&|\w+[._]\w+/u', mb_substr( $m, 1, mb_strlen( $m, 'UTF-8' ) - 1, 'UTF-8' ) )
        ) {
            return $m;
        } else {
            //if all else fails, then no more fringe-cases; uppercase the word
            $m = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( $m, 0, 1, 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8' ) .
                 mb_substr( $m, 1, mb_strlen( $m, 'UTF-8' ), 'UTF-8' );
        }

        return $m;
    }

}
```

**`locales.json`:**

```
{
    "af_NA": "Afrikaans (Namibia)",
    "af_ZA": "Afrikaans (South Africa)",
    "af": "Afrikaans",
    "ak_GH": "Akan (Ghana)",
    "ak": "Akan",
    "sq_AL": "Albanian (Albania)",
    "sq": "Albanian",
    "am_ET": "Amharic (Ethiopia)",
    "am": "Amharic",
    "ar_DZ": "Arabic (Algeria)",
    "ar_BH": "Arabic (Bahrain)",
    "ar_EG": "Arabic (Egypt)",
    "ar_IQ": "Arabic (Iraq)",
    "ar_JO": "Arabic (Jordan)",
    "ar_KW": "Arabic (Kuwait)",
    "ar_LB": "Arabic (Lebanon)",
    "ar_LY": "Arabic (Libya)",
    "ar_MA": "Arabic (Morocco)",
    "ar_OM": "Arabic (Oman)",
    "ar_QA": "Arabic (Qatar)",
    "ar_SA": "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)",
    "ar_SD": "Arabic (Sudan)",
    "ar_SY": "Arabic (Syria)",
    "ar_TN": "Arabic (Tunisia)",
    "ar_AE": "Arabic (United Arab Emirates)",
    "ar_YE": "Arabic (Yemen)",
    "ar": "Arabic",
    "hy_AM": "Armenian (Armenia)",
    "hy": "Armenian",
    "as_IN": "Assamese (India)",
    "as": "Assamese",
    "asa_TZ": "Asu (Tanzania)",
    "asa": "Asu",
    "az_Cyrl": "Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)",
    "az_Cyrl_AZ": "Azerbaijani (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan)",
    "az_Latn": "Azerbaijani (Latin)",
    "az_Latn_AZ": "Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan)",
    "az": "Azerbaijani",
    "bm_ML": "Bambara (Mali)",
    "bm": "Bambara",
    "eu_ES": "Basque (Spain)",
    "eu": "Basque",
    "be_BY": "Belarusian (Belarus)",
    "be": "Belarusian",
    "bem_ZM": "Bemba (Zambia)",
    "bem": "Bemba",
    "bez_TZ": "Bena (Tanzania)",
    "bez": "Bena",
    "bn_BD": "Bengali (Bangladesh)",
    "bn_IN": "Bengali (India)",
    "bn": "Bengali",
    "bs_BA": "Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)",
    "bs": "Bosnian",
    "bg_BG": "Bulgarian (Bulgaria)",
    "bg": "Bulgarian",
    "my_MM": "Burmese (Myanmar [Burma])",
    "my": "Burmese",
    "ca_ES": "Catalan (Spain)",
    "ca": "Catalan",
    "tzm_Latn": "Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin)",
    "tzm_Latn_MA": "Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin, Morocco)",
    "tzm": "Central Morocco Tamazight",
    "chr_US": "Cherokee (United States)",
    "chr": "Cherokee",
    "cgg_UG": "Chiga (Uganda)",
    "cgg": "Chiga",
    "zh_Hans": "Chinese (Simplified Han)",
    "zh_Hans_CN": "Chinese (Simplified Han, China)",
    "zh_Hans_HK": "Chinese (Simplified Han, Hong Kong SAR China)",
    "zh_Hans_MO": "Chinese (Simplified Han, Macau SAR China)",
    "zh_Hans_SG": "Chinese (Simplified Han, Singapore)",
    "zh_Hant": "Chinese (Traditional Han)",
    "zh_Hant_HK": "Chinese (Traditional Han, Hong Kong SAR China)",
    "zh_Hant_MO": "Chinese (Traditional Han, Macau SAR China)",
    "zh_Hant_TW": "Chinese (Traditional Han, Taiwan)",
    "zh": "Chinese",
    "kw_GB": "Cornish (United Kingdom)",
    "kw": "Cornish",
    "hr_HR": "Croatian (Croatia)",
    "hr": "Croatian",
    "cs_CZ": "Czech (Czech Republic)",
    "cs": "Czech",
    "da_DK": "Danish (Denmark)",
    "da": "Danish",
    "nl_BE": "Dutch (Belgium)",
    "nl_NL": "Dutch (Netherlands)",
    "nl": "Dutch",
    "ebu_KE": "Embu (Kenya)",
    "ebu": "Embu",
    "en_AS": "English (American Samoa)",
    "en_AU": "English (Australia)",
    "en_BE": "English (Belgium)",
    "en_BZ": "English (Belize)",
    "en_BW": "English (Botswana)",
    "en_CA": "English (Canada)",
    "en_GU": "English (Guam)",
    "en_HK": "English (Hong Kong SAR China)",
    "en_IN": "English (India)",
    "en_IE": "English (Ireland)",
    "en_JM": "English (Jamaica)",
    "en_MT": "English (Malta)",
    "en_MH": "English (Marshall Islands)",
    "en_MU": "English (Mauritius)",
    "en_NA": "English (Namibia)",
    "en_NZ": "English (New Zealand)",
    "en_MP": "English (Northern Mariana Islands)",
    "en_PK": "English (Pakistan)",
    "en_PH": "English (Philippines)",
    "en_SG": "English (Singapore)",
    "en_ZA": "English (South Africa)",
    "en_TT": "English (Trinidad and Tobago)",
    "en_UM": "English (U.S. Minor Outlying Islands)",
    "en_VI": "English (U.S. Virgin Islands)",
    "en_GB": "English (United Kingdom)",
    "en_US": "English (United States)",
    "en_ZW": "English (Zimbabwe)",
    "en": "English",
    "eo": "Esperanto",
    "et_EE": "Estonian (Estonia)",
    "et": "Estonian",
    "ee_GH": "Ewe (Ghana)",
    "ee_TG": "Ewe (Togo)",
    "ee": "Ewe",
    "fo_FO": "Faroese (Faroe Islands)",
    "fo": "Faroese",
    "fil_PH": "Filipino (Philippines)",
    "fil": "Filipino",
    "fi_FI": "Finnish (Finland)",
    "fi": "Finnish",
    "fr_BE": "French (Belgium)",
    "fr_BJ": "French (Benin)",
    "fr_BF": "French (Burkina Faso)",
    "fr_BI": "French (Burundi)",
    "fr_CM": "French (Cameroon)",
    "fr_CA": "French (Canada)",
    "fr_CF": "French (Central African Republic)",
    "fr_TD": "French (Chad)",
    "fr_KM": "French (Comoros)",
    "fr_CG": "French (Congo - Brazzaville)",
    "fr_CD": "French (Congo - Kinshasa)",
    "fr_CI": "French (Côte d’Ivoire)",
    "fr_DJ": "French (Djibouti)",
    "fr_GQ": "French (Equatorial Guinea)",
    "fr_FR": "French (France)",
    "fr_GA": "French (Gabon)",
    "fr_GP": "French (Guadeloupe)",
    "fr_GN": "French (Guinea)",
    "fr_LU": "French (Luxembourg)",
    "fr_MG": "French (Madagascar)",
    "fr_ML": "French (Mali)",
    "fr_MQ": "French (Martinique)",
    "fr_MC": "French (Monaco)",
    "fr_NE": "French (Niger)",
    "fr_RW": "French (Rwanda)",
    "fr_RE": "French (Réunion)",
    "fr_BL": "French (Saint Barthélemy)",
    "fr_MF": "French (Saint Martin)",
    "fr_SN": "French (Senegal)",
    "fr_CH": "French (Switzerland)",
    "fr_TG": "French (Togo)",
    "fr": "French",
    "ff_SN": "Fulah (Senegal)",
    "ff": "Fulah",
    "gl_ES": "Galician (Spain)",
    "gl": "Galician",
    "lg_UG": "Ganda (Uganda)",
    "lg": "Ganda",
    "ka_GE": "Georgian (Georgia)",
    "ka": "Georgian",
    "de_AT": "German (Austria)",
    "de_BE": "German (Belgium)",
    "de_DE": "German (Germany)",
    "de_LI": "German (Liechtenstein)",
    "de_LU": "German (Luxembourg)",
    "de_CH": "German (Switzerland)",
    "de": "German",
    "el_CY": "Greek (Cyprus)",
    "el_GR": "Greek (Greece)",
    "el": "Greek",
    "gu_IN": "Gujarati (India)",
    "gu": "Gujarati",
    "guz_KE": "Gusii (Kenya)",
    "guz": "Gusii",
    "ha_Latn": "Hausa (Latin)",
    "ha_Latn_GH": "Hausa (Latin, Ghana)",
    "ha_Latn_NE": "Hausa (Latin, Niger)",
    "ha_Latn_NG": "Hausa (Latin, Nigeria)",
    "ha": "Hausa",
    "haw_US": "Hawaiian (United States)",
    "haw": "Hawaiian",
    "he_IL": "Hebrew (Israel)",
    "he": "Hebrew",
    "hi_IN": "Hindi (India)",
    "hi": "Hindi",
    "hu_HU": "Hungarian (Hungary)",
    "hu": "Hungarian",
    "is_IS": "Icelandic (Iceland)",
    "is": "Icelandic",
    "ig_NG": "Igbo (Nigeria)",
    "ig": "Igbo",
    "id_ID": "Indonesian (Indonesia)",
    "id": "Indonesian",
    "ga_IE": "Irish (Ireland)",
    "ga": "Irish",
    "it_IT": "Italian (Italy)",
    "it_CH": "Italian (Switzerland)",
    "it": "Italian",
    "ja_JP": "Japanese (Japan)",
    "ja": "Japanese",
    "kea_CV": "Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)",
    "kea": "Kabuverdianu",
    "kab_DZ": "Kabyle (Algeria)",
    "kab": "Kabyle",
    "kl_GL": "Kalaallisut (Greenland)",
    "kl": "Kalaallisut",
    "kln_KE": "Kalenjin (Kenya)",
    "kln": "Kalenjin",
    "kam_KE": "Kamba (Kenya)",
    "kam": "Kamba",
    "kn_IN": "Kannada (India)",
    "kn": "Kannada",
    "kk_Cyrl": "Kazakh (Cyrillic)",
    "kk_Cyrl_KZ": "Kazakh (Cyrillic, Kazakhstan)",
    "kk": "Kazakh",
    "km_KH": "Khmer (Cambodia)",
    "km": "Khmer",
    "ki_KE": "Kikuyu (Kenya)",
    "ki": "Kikuyu",
    "rw_RW": "Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)",
    "rw": "Kinyarwanda",
    "kok_IN": "Konkani (India)",
    "kok": "Konkani",
    "ko_KR": "Korean (South Korea)",
    "ko": "Korean",
    "khq_ML": "Koyra Chiini (Mali)",
    "khq": "Koyra Chiini",
    "ses_ML": "Koyraboro Senni (Mali)",
    "ses": "Koyraboro Senni",
    "lag_TZ": "Langi (Tanzania)",
    "lag": "Langi",
    "lv_LV": "Latvian (Latvia)",
    "lv": "Latvian",
    "lt_LT": "Lithuanian (Lithuania)",
    "lt": "Lithuanian",
    "luo_KE": "Luo (Kenya)",
    "luo": "Luo",
    "luy_KE": "Luyia (Kenya)",
    "luy": "Luyia",
    "mk_MK": "Macedonian (Macedonia)",
    "mk": "Macedonian",
    "jmc_TZ": "Machame (Tanzania)",
    "jmc": "Machame",
    "kde_TZ": "Makonde (Tanzania)",
    "kde": "Makonde",
    "mg_MG": "Malagasy (Madagascar)",
    "mg": "Malagasy",
    "ms_BN": "Malay (Brunei)",
    "ms_MY": "Malay (Malaysia)",
    "ms": "Malay",
    "ml_IN": "Malayalam (India)",
    "ml": "Malayalam",
    "mt_MT": "Maltese (Malta)",
    "mt": "Maltese",
    "gv_GB": "Manx (United Kingdom)",
    "gv": "Manx",
    "mr_IN": "Marathi (India)",
    "mr": "Marathi",
    "mas_KE": "Masai (Kenya)",
    "mas_TZ": "Masai (Tanzania)",
    "mas": "Masai",
    "mer_KE": "Meru (Kenya)",
    "mer": "Meru",
    "mfe_MU": "Morisyen (Mauritius)",
    "mfe": "Morisyen",
    "naq_NA": "Nama (Namibia)",
    "naq": "Nama",
    "ne_IN": "Nepali (India)",
    "ne_NP": "Nepali (Nepal)",
    "ne": "Nepali",
    "nd_ZW": "North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)",
    "nd": "North Ndebele",
    "nb_NO": "Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)",
    "nb": "Norwegian Bokmål",
    "nn_NO": "Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)",
    "nn": "Norwegian Nynorsk",
    "nyn_UG": "Nyankole (Uganda)",
    "nyn": "Nyankole",
    "or_IN": "Oriya (India)",
    "or": "Oriya",
    "om_ET": "Oromo (Ethiopia)",
    "om_KE": "Oromo (Kenya)",
    "om": "Oromo",
    "ps_AF": "Pashto (Afghanistan)",
    "ps": "Pashto",
    "fa_AF": "Persian (Afghanistan)",
    "fa_IR": "Persian (Iran)",
    "fa": "Persian",
    "pl_PL": "Polish (Poland)",
    "pl": "Polish",
    "pt_BR": "Portuguese (Brazil)",
    "pt_GW": "Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)",
    "pt_MZ": "Portuguese (Mozambique)",
    "pt_PT": "Portuguese (Portugal)",
    "pt": "Portuguese",
    "pa_Arab": "Punjabi (Arabic)",
    "pa_Arab_PK": "Punjabi (Arabic, Pakistan)",
    "pa_Guru": "Punjabi (Gurmukhi)",
    "pa_Guru_IN": "Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India)",
    "pa": "Punjabi",
    "ro_MD": "Romanian (Moldova)",
    "ro_RO": "Romanian (Romania)",
    "ro": "Romanian",
    "rm_CH": "Romansh (Switzerland)",
    "rm": "Romansh",
    "rof_TZ": "Rombo (Tanzania)",
    "rof": "Rombo",
    "ru_MD": "Russian (Moldova)",
    "ru_RU": "Russian (Russia)",
    "ru_UA": "Russian (Ukraine)",
    "ru": "Russian",
    "rwk_TZ": "Rwa (Tanzania)",
    "rwk": "Rwa",
    "saq_KE": "Samburu (Kenya)",
    "saq": "Samburu",
    "sg_CF": "Sango (Central African Republic)",
    "sg": "Sango",
    "seh_MZ": "Sena (Mozambique)",
    "seh": "Sena",
    "sr_Cyrl": "Serbian (Cyrillic)",
    "sr_Cyrl_BA": "Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)",
    "sr_Cyrl_ME": "Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)",
    "sr_Cyrl_RS": "Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)",
    "sr_Latn": "Serbian (Latin)",
    "sr_Latn_BA": "Serbian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)",
    "sr_Latn_ME": "Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)",
    "sr_Latn_RS": "Serbian (Latin, Serbia)",
    "sr": "Serbian",
    "sn_ZW": "Shona (Zimbabwe)",
    "sn": "Shona",
    "ii_CN": "Sichuan Yi (China)",
    "ii": "Sichuan Yi",
    "si_LK": "Sinhala (Sri Lanka)",
    "si": "Sinhala",
    "sk_SK": "Slovak (Slovakia)",
    "sk": "Slovak",
    "sl_SI": "Slovenian (Slovenia)",
    "sl": "Slovenian",
    "xog_UG": "Soga (Uganda)",
    "xog": "Soga",
    "so_DJ": "Somali (Djibouti)",
    "so_ET": "Somali (Ethiopia)",
    "so_KE": "Somali (Kenya)",
    "so_SO": "Somali (Somalia)",
    "so": "Somali",
    "es_AR": "Spanish (Argentina)",
    "es_BO": "Spanish (Bolivia)",
    "es_CL": "Spanish (Chile)",
    "es_CO": "Spanish (Colombia)",
    "es_CR": "Spanish (Costa Rica)",
    "es_DO": "Spanish (Dominican Republic)",
    "es_EC": "Spanish (Ecuador)",
    "es_SV": "Spanish (El Salvador)",
    "es_GQ": "Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)",
    "es_GT": "Spanish (Guatemala)",
    "es_HN": "Spanish (Honduras)",
    "es_419": "Spanish (Latin America)",
    "es_MX": "Spanish (Mexico)",
    "es_NI": "Spanish (Nicaragua)",
    "es_PA": "Spanish (Panama)",
    "es_PY": "Spanish (Paraguay)",
    "es_PE": "Spanish (Peru)",
    "es_PR": "Spanish (Puerto Rico)",
    "es_ES": "Spanish (Spain)",
    "es_US": "Spanish (United States)",
    "es_UY": "Spanish (Uruguay)",
    "es_VE": "Spanish (Venezuela)",
    "es": "Spanish",
    "sw_KE": "Swahili (Kenya)",
    "sw_TZ": "Swahili (Tanzania)",
    "sw": "Swahili",
    "sv_FI": "Swedish (Finland)",
    "sv_SE": "Swedish (Sweden)",
    "sv": "Swedish",
    "gsw_CH": "Swiss German (Switzerland)",
    "gsw": "Swiss German",
    "shi_Latn": "Tachelhit (Latin)",
    "shi_Latn_MA": "Tachelhit (Latin, Morocco)",
    "shi_Tfng": "Tachelhit (Tifinagh)",
    "shi_Tfng_MA": "Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco)",
    "shi": "Tachelhit",
    "dav_KE": "Taita (Kenya)",
    "dav": "Taita",
    "ta_IN": "Tamil (India)",
    "ta_LK": "Tamil (Sri Lanka)",
    "ta": "Tamil",
    "te_IN": "Telugu (India)",
    "te": "Telugu",
    "teo_KE": "Teso (Kenya)",
    "teo_UG": "Teso (Uganda)",
    "teo": "Teso",
    "th_TH": "Thai (Thailand)",
    "th": "Thai",
    "bo_CN": "Tibetan (China)",
    "bo_IN": "Tibetan (India)",
    "bo": "Tibetan",
    "ti_ER": "Tigrinya (Eritrea)",
    "ti_ET": "Tigrinya (Ethiopia)",
    "ti": "Tigrinya",
    "to_TO": "Tonga (Tonga)",
    "to": "Tonga",
    "tr_TR": "Turkish (Turkey)",
    "tr": "Turkish",
    "uk_UA": "Ukrainian (Ukraine)",
    "uk": "Ukrainian",
    "ur_IN": "Urdu (India)",
    "ur_PK": "Urdu (Pakistan)",
    "ur": "Urdu",
    "uz_Arab": "Uzbek (Arabic)",
    "uz_Arab_AF": "Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan)",
    "uz_Cyrl": "Uzbek (Cyrillic)",
    "uz_Cyrl_UZ": "Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan)",
    "uz_Latn": "Uzbek (Latin)",
    "uz_Latn_UZ": "Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan)",
    "uz": "Uzbek",
    "vi_VN": "Vietnamese (Vietnam)",
    "vi": "Vietnamese",
    "vun_TZ": "Vunjo (Tanzania)",
    "vun": "Vunjo",
    "cy_GB": "Welsh (United Kingdom)",
    "cy": "Welsh",
    "yo_NG": "Yoruba (Nigeria)",
    "yo": "Yoruba",
    "zu_ZA": "Zulu (South Africa)",
    "zu": "Zulu"
    }
```